# SwiftUI how to add an observer to a service MenuBarExtra app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

Because this is a service appliction (Application is agent) and no windows. And I want to add an observer for listening the pasteboard change, but I don't know where to add an observer.

Here's the sample code:

```
struct Demo: App {
    let pub = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSPasteboardDidChange)
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
          SettingView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra("Menu Bar", systemImage: "swift") {
            MenuView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
            Button("Perferences...") { // TODO }
            Button("Quit") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So there's no place to add a `onReceive(_:perform:)` methods. Also in this situation, I don't know how to use coredata here. Because I want to update CoreData when the pasteboard changes.